# Disable schedule function in VOLTTRON

Tags: schedule, volttron

To execute the function periodically, the following command is used.

`self.core.schedule(periodic(t), periodic_function)`

I would like to disable the above function when certain conditions are met. Anyone knows how?

Comment: I think the easiest way to do it is in the periodic_function itself.   Assuming this is in the agent class itself you could have a class level boolean as to whether to proceed or just return from the function itself.

Comment: Is this function supposed to be a cancel and never come up again?

Comment: @Craig   
 Do you recommend using loops like "for" or "while"?
And I want to create or delete the periodic action of the function according to the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@GYOON

I would do what the code here does: https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron/blob/master/services/core/VolttronCentralPlatform/vcplatform/agent.py#L320

Basically what is going on is in the agent's onstart/onconfig method a function that is to be executed is called in a spawn later greenlet

```
class MyAgent(Agent):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self._periodic_event = None
    self.enabled = True

  @Core.receiver('onstart')
  def onstart(self, sender, **kwargs):
    self.core.spawn_later(1, self._my_periodic_event)
  
  def _my_periodic_event(self):
    if self._periodic_event is not None:
      self._periodic_event.cancel()

    # do stuff here within this event loop
    
    if self.enabled:
      # note this is an internal volttron function see the referenced link for
      # import
      now = get_aware_utc_now()
      next_update_time = now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=20)
    
    
      self._periodic_event = self.core.schedule(next_update_time, self._my_periodic_event)
```

The good thing about this is it allows you to have complete control over the scheduling process.  The enable, disable, when to start etc.  You can change the number of seconds if you need to with member variables.

Again sorry for the late response on this, but hopefully this helps!

Comment: One more thing...this also allows you to start the event in different parts of your code if you would like to.